# Get probability of no positive results in a population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size

I have a population of say 100,000 records that can be either Positive or Negative (true probability of Positive is very small, but unknown - may even be zero).

I want to take a sample and estimate how many Positive cases are in the population, to be able to say something along the lines of "I'm 95% confident there are less than 50 positive cases in the population" or even better show my confidence there are no positive cases eg. "I'm 87% confident there are no positive cases".

How can I do the following:

- What tests do I want to be doing here? From doing some research it looks like I want to use a Proportion Hypothesis test [such as on this page](http://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/201/hyptest/hypprob.htm). Is this correct? How would I set it up for my case?
- I can adjust my sample size, how do I determine the smallest sample size I would need for such a test.

Comment: A statement like the ones you suggested doesn't necessarily result from hypothesis testing. You might be better served by a confidence interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic ball-and-urn problem.  Most ball-and-urn problems can be associated with a particular probability distribution; the correct choice of pmf for a given problem depends upon the specific details of that problem but here is a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem#Examples_of_urn_problems) of some of the more common ones.  The correct pmf to use for this problem is the [hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) distribution.  In the notation of the wikipedia page provided in the link, $N=100000$, while $K$ signifies an unknown number of "white balls" which represent a positive outcome among the 100000 records, $(N-K)$ signifies the number of "black balls" which represent a negative outcome, $n$ represents the size of the much smaller $(n \ll N)$ random subsample that is being used for estimation purposes, and $k$ represents the number of white balls actually observed in the $n$-sized subsample.  From the definition of the hypergeometric distribution, the probability of drawing $k$ white balls is $$p(k|K,n,N) = \frac{\left(\begin{array}{c} K \\ k \end{array} \right) \left(\begin{array}{c} N-K \\ n-k \end{array} \right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c} N \\ n \end{array} \right)}$$  For this problem, $k$, $n$, and $N$ are known, and $K$ is the unknown quantity about which we wish to perform statistical reasoning.  Evidently we need to "invert" the above pmf somehow to find $p(K|k,n,N)$.

We can obtain this "inverse" (so to speak) distribution by applying Bayes rule: $$p(H_{i}|D,B) = \frac{p(D|H_{i},B)p(H_{i}|B)}{p(D,B)} = \frac{p(D|H_{i},B)p(H_{i}|B)}{\sum\limits_{j} p(D|H_{j},B)p(H_{j}|B)}$$  In the Bayes rule notation, $D$ represents the data, i.e., the known observation $k$, while $B$ signifies background information, such as $N$ and $n$.  The $H_{i}$ represent a set of mutually exclusive hypotheses about the unknown quantity $K$.  For example, $H_{0}$ represents the hypothesis that $K=0$, $H_{1}$, the hypothesis that $K=1$, etc.  Thus, we see that $p(D|H_{i},B)$ is equivalent to $p(k|K,n,N)$, the expression already provided above.  Bayesian theory requires that we define a so-called [prior distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability), represented in the Bayes rule expression above by the term $p(H_{i}|B)$.  Bayesian theory provides us some latitude in how to choose the prior, meaning that there isn't necessarily a single correct choice, only that our choice should be reasonable and justifiable.  The problem statement specifies that $K$ is known to be not all that large; i.e., $(K \ll N)$.  So, let's imagine that we can specify some $K_{max}$, a maximum plausible value for $K$ such that we are sure that $K < K_{max}$, although we don't know anything more for sure a priori about $K$ other than that.  Then we may select the prior probability for each of the hypotheses $H_{i}$ as $p(H_{i}|B) = \frac{1}{K_{max}}$.  For example, if we were to assume that the parent sample $N$ contained no more than 1% positives, then we would choose $K_{max} = 1000$, and set $$\begin{array}{ccc} p(H_{0}|B) & = & \frac{1}{1000} \\ p(H_{1}|B) & = & \frac{1}{1000} \\ & \vdots & \\ p(H_{999}|B) & = & \frac{1}{1000} \end{array}$$ with $p(H_{1000}|B) = 0$ and similar for all $i \ge 1000$.

Plugging all of this into Bayes rule, we find that $$P(K|k,n,N) = \frac{p(k|K,n,N)}{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{(K_{max}-1)} p(k|K,n,N)}$$ (note that the prior probabilities ultimately all cancel).  This expression can be used to answer statistical questions about $K$.  For example, to calculate the probability that $K=0$, one literally just plugs in $K=0$, plus the known values for $k$, $n$ and $N$.  To calculate a 95% confidence limit on the maximum size of $K$, sum over the individual probabilities for $K=0$, $K=1$, $K=2$, etc., and simply keep increasing $K$ and adding to the sum until you reach some value such that the sum over all of the individual probabilities is 95%.  (In practice, you may need to use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) in order to estimate some of the factorials that you will need to calculate.)

One last point: the "answer" that you get for your statistical estimate of $K$ will depend strongly on $n$, the size of the subsample.  This makes sense, intuitively: if $n$ is large, say $n=50000$, or in other words half the size of the parent sample of $N=100000$, you will be giving yourself a lot more information to work with than if $n=50$, and that difference will have a profound effect on how much you think you "know" (in a statistical sense) about $K$.